# Trim reads 1kb upstream of sequence

Tags: python, trimming, multi-fasta

I need a quick way to trim multiple reads in a FASTA file. I need to trim everything that is 1kbp upstream of this sequence `AAGAGATGTTCAATCGTTTAAACAAATTCCAAGCTGCTTTAGCTTTGGCCCTTTACTCTCA`.

I figure a quick python script might be the way to go but I'm not sure if there's a tool that already does that (i.e. Trimmomatic or something like it) that would be able to do that for me.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the source of these reads (i.e. sequencing platform)? Is it necessary to account for some error in the recognition sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using [biopython](/questions/tagged/biopython). Note that the [`Seq`](https://biopython.org/wiki/Seq) object has a number of methods that act just like those of a Python string. One of these is the [`find()`](https://biopython.org/docs/1.80/api/Bio.Seq.html#Bio.Seq.SequenceDataAbstractBaseClass.find) method, which returns the index of the first occurrence of the sequence if found. Replace with [`rfind()`](https://biopython.org/docs/1.80/api/Bio.Seq.html#Bio.Seq.SequenceDataAbstractBaseClass.rfind) if you want the last occurrence if that makes more sense. This solution uses a generator to avoid storing the entire list of trimmed sequences in memory:

```
import argparse
import contextlib
import gzip
import sys

from Bio import SeqIO
```

```
def trim_fasta(fileobj, sequence, num_bases):
    """
    Trim num_bases upstream of the sequence provided
    """
    for record in SeqIO.parse(fileobj, 'fasta'):
        index = record.seq.find(sequence)
        if index != -1 and index > num_bases:
            record = record[index-num_bases:]
        yield record
```

```
def open_file(filename, mode='r'):
    if filename.endswith('.gz'):
        return gzip.open(filename, mode)
    else:
        return open(filename, mode)
```

```
def get_argument_parser():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)

    group = parser.add_argument_group('input options')
    group.add_argument(
        "fasta",
        type=str,
        metavar="FILE",
        help="The input FASTA file",
    )
    group.add_argument(
        "sequence",
        type=str,
        metavar="STR",
        help="The sequence to find and trim",
    )

    group = parser.add_argument_group('trimming options')
    group.add_argument(
        "-n",
        "--num_bases",
        type=int,
        metavar="INT",
        default=1000,
        help="Trim INT bases upstream of input sequence",
    )

    group = parser.add_argument_group('output options')
    group.add_argument(
        "-o",
        "--output",
        type=str,
        metavar="FILE",
        default='-',
        help="Write the filtered output to FILE (default: stdout)",
    )
    group.add_argument(
        "-f",
        "--force",
        action='store_true',
        help="Overwrite the output file if it exists",
    )

    group = parser.add_argument_group('additional options')
    group.add_argument(
        "-h",
        "--help",
        action="help",
        help="Show this help message and exit",
    )

    return parser
```

```
def main():

    parser = get_argument_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
        if args.output != '-':
            out = stack.enter_context(open_file(args.output, 'wt' if args.force else 'xt'))
        else:
            out = sys.stdout

        input_fasta = stack.enter_context(open_file(args.fasta))
        trimmed_reads = trim_fasta(input_fasta, args.sequence, args.num_bases)

        SeqIO.write(trimmed_reads, out, "fasta-2line")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

---

```
usage: trim_reads.py [-n INT] [-o FILE] [-f] [-h] FILE STR

input options:
  FILE                  The input FASTA file
  STR                   The sequence to find and trim

trimming options:
  -n INT, --num_bases INT
                        Trim INT bases upstream of input sequence

output options:
  -o FILE, --output FILE
                        Write the filtered output to FILE (default: stdout)
  -f, --force           Overwrite the output file if it exists

additional options:
  -h, --help            Show this help message and exit
```